# Validate expression/infix in python

Tags: python, expression, infix-notation, arithmetic-expressions

How do I validate an expression/infix in python? Is it possible?
For example:

```
a-d*9
5-(a*0.3-d+(0.4-e))/k*5
(a-d*9)/(k-y-4.3*e)+(t-7*c)
```

Comment: the answer is simple: create a parser. Could you show what you have tried so far? Have you a specific problem?

Comment: I'm created a parser. Before execute it. I need a validate it.

Comment: @Zeck: The parser validates the expression by failing to parse.  If the parser fails to complete, the expression was invalid.  You don't validate **before** parsing.  Validation is a consequence of parsing.  if the parser finishes it was valid.  If the parser fails it was invalid.  Don't "pre-validate".  That's wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want Python-style expressions, you can use the parser in the `ast` module and check for `SyntaxError`:

```
>>> ast.parse('5-(a*0.3-d+(0.4-e))/k*5')
<_ast.Module object at 0x7fc7bdd9e790>
>>> ast.parse('5-(a*0.3-d+(0.4-e))/k*')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/ast.py", line 37, in parse
    return compile(expr, filename, mode, PyCF_ONLY_AST)
  File "<unknown>", line 1
    5-(a*0.3-d+(0.4-e))/k*
                        ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

Though that might parse much more than you actually need:

```
>>> ast.parse('def spam(): return "ham"')
<_ast.Module object at 0x7fc7bdd9e790>
```

so you might want to inspect the returned parse tree carefully.